# Синтаксическая ошибка около "AND"

Tags: c#, sql

Не вижу синтаксическую ошибку в sql-запросе:

```
sqlUpdate =
            @"UPDATE VIN_номер SET VIN_номер = @VIN AND Регион_Страна_Фирма_расшифровка = @Страна 
            AND Модель_расшифровка = @Модель AND Колесная_база_расшифровка = @База AND Тип_кузова_расшифровка = @Кузов 
            AND Двигатель_расшифровка = @Двигатель AND Тип_трансмиссии_расшифровка = @Коробка AND 
            Год_выпуска_расшифровка = @Год AND Отделение_завода_расшифровка = @Завод AND Порядковый_номер = @Номер WHERE ID = @ID";
```

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 4):

```
@"UPDATE VIN_номер SET VIN_номер = @VIN, Регион_Страна_Фирма_расшифровка = @Страна, ... 
  ..., Порядковый_номер = @Номер WHERE ID = @ID"
```

Comment: Так а разве так можно сворачивать и что от этого поменяется?

Comment: @АндрейПавлов Что такое "сворачивать"? В `UPDATE` устанавливамые значения полей перечисляются через запятую.

Comment: @АндрейПавлов А вы откройте документацию или стандарт ANSI-92 и почитайте. Вот просто любопытно: ведь вы же откуда-то взяли эту форму через AND, откуда? Неужто сами придумали? Если сами - то отчего удивляетесь, когда вам пересказывают правильные вещи из документации. А если не сами - то откуда выкопали такую странную форму. Просто везде написано через запятую: [раз](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [два](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)...